# Why the vtkSelectPolyData returns wrong area?

Tags: python, vtk

I use the points as a loop input in a vtkSelectPolyData filter,then enable generation of selection scalars, and get the enclosed surface patch using vtkClipPolyData but sometimes vtkSelectPolyData can’t select area inside the loop and gives the wrong area or returns vtkSelectPolyData filter can not follow the edge.I tried to preprocess the poly data with vtkCleanPolyData but the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to follow the edges in input data, then stop using vtkClipPolyData.
Use vtkSelectPolyData with GenerateSelectionScalarOff(), if you want both data inside and outside the loop, do make sure to use GenerateUnselectedOutputOn(), this should give you second (unselected) output. Remember to use the correct selection mode like "SetSelectionModeToSmallestRegion()" or "SetSelectionModeToLargestRegion()" or whatever other mode that suits your needs.
Do note that vtkSelectPolyData has two outputs to get selected data use "GetOutput()" for second output use "GetUnselectedOutput()".